# Reading values for CNContact InstantMessageAddressesKey

Tags: swift, contacts

I am trying to work with all contacts on my iPhone who have a specific code which is stored in the Instant Message field of the contacts.

The code for fetching:

```swift
func fetchAllContacts() async {
    // Get access to the Contacts Store
    let store = CNContactStore()
    // Specify which data keys we ant to fetch
    let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactInstantMessageAddressesKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
    // Create an fetch request
    let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys)
    // Call method to fetch all contacts
    do {
        try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest, usingBlock: { contact, result in
        
            if !contact.instantMessageAddresses.isEmpty  {
                print(contact.givenName)
                print(contact.instantMessageAddresses)
            }
        })
    }
    catch {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

It works fine and the following contact information is printed to the console:

```
Roman
[<CNLabeledValue: 0x282783100: identifier=0E327523-281C-49D7-A4A1-7E5FF9F10F1C, label=(nil), value=<CNMutableInstantMessageAddress: 0x283ccdda0: username=01 1244 131 01, userIdentifier=(nil), service=, teamIdentifier=(nil), bundleIdentifiers=(nil)>, iOSLegacyIdentifier=0>]
```

How can I get the username string? I need this string "01 1244 131 01" and I don't know how to read this string in a variable.

I tried the following, but it throws an error:

```swift
print ("C-Value: \(contact.value(forKey: "username")!)")
```

Comment: `contact.instantMessageAddresses` is an array. You have to enumerate them. The objects are https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cninstantmessageaddress?language=objc so you need to retrieve the `username` from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the documentation for [`instantMessageAddresses`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontact/1403147-instantmessageaddresses):

> This property is an array of [`CNLabeledValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cnlabeledvalue) objects, each of which has a label and a [`CNInstantMessageAddress`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cninstantmessageaddress) value.

Instead of `print(contact.instantMessageAddresses)` you could use the following to print the first address (if any):

```swift
print(contact.instantMessageAddresses.first?.value.username)
```

Of course if the contact has more than one instant message address you will need to iterate through the array and access all of them.

This will create an array of usernames (containing 0 or more results):

```swift
let usernames = contact.instantMessageAddresses.map { $0.value.username }
```